# Why Node.js parse json from iOS in wrong format?

Tags: iphone, json, node.js, afnetworking

In iOS, I have an array of dictionary

```
dishs =     (
            {
        amount = 1;
        itemId = 576d315a7d24aa5085fe0dc3;
    },
            {
        amount = 2;
        itemId = 57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50d;
    },
            {
        amount = 1;
        itemId = 57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50c;
    }
);
```

I send it by AFN like

```
parameters = @{@"token":token,  @"dishs":items};
[manager PUT:[url absoluteString] parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
```

But in Node.js I get:

```
[ { amount: [ '1', '2', '1' ],
itemId: 
 [ '576d315a7d24aa5085fe0dc3',
   '57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50d',
   '57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50c' ] } ]
```

If the array only have one item, then node will get json correctly.
iOS:

```
 dishs =     (
            {
        amount = 1;
        itemId = 576d315a7d24aa5085fe0dc3;
    }
);
```

Node.js:

```
[ { amount: '1', itemId: '576d315a7d24aa5085fe0dc3' } ]
```

If I use postman to send request Node also can get data in correct format:

```
[ { itemId: '57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50b', amount: 3 },
  { itemId: '57666d75c8f2cb97bb07e50a', amount: 5 } ]
```

I am so confused that why json in Node.js be parsed in this format and how to fix it?